# Why Queues user's can't approval record from email after Process Automation Settings enabled?

Tags: approval-process, process-automation

I have setup an Approval Process in my system and added a queue and a user for approval.

After that, I enabled the Process Automation Settings so that user can approve from the email itself.

[image]

And below is the one user and one queue who responsible for approval

[image]

when I submit a record for approval

Plan head is user and get this email

[image]

Just notice here in this email we will get ***reply to this email with one of these words in the first line of the email message: APPROVE, APPROVED, YES, REJECT, REJECTED, NO*** and when I reply APPROVE in email it get approve for plan ahead user

but when see queue user email

[image]

this email doesn't contains ***reply to this email with one of these words in the first line of the email message: APPROVE, APPROVED, YES, REJECT, REJECTED, NO***

I can't approve from email for queue.

Any help/suggestion why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation. You can reduce confusion by modifying your approval email template to omit the language about replying. You can also vote on the idea here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000iHh7AAE